# Laravel relational queries to use in angular

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

HI im angularizing a laravel application currently in my blade template i use eloquent relations and some other function in foreach to get other table values how i can achieve this with angular. 
I have to create **new http calls in ng-repeat** or write a query fetch all data at once and send to angular? what is the best case scenario. below is my laravel code example.

```
@foreach ($jobs as $record)
 <tr>
    <td>{{$record->id}}</td>
    <td><a href="">{{$record->title}}</a></td>
    <td>{{ Offer::hired($record->id) }}</td>
    <td>{{$record->submissions->count()}}</td>
    <td>{!! jobStatusLabel($record->jobStatus) !!}</td>

 </tr>   
@endforeach
```

Comment: The best way is to make your backend return JSON's. You can then let angular to consume those JSONs and use ng-repeat as you need.

Comment: Thats right but then i have to return JSON at once in this case for jobs  writings new sql quires that return all the data that relate to jobs.

Comment: That's right. You'll have to do that. I don't see any big deal there.

Comment: lot of other quires are also there and i can not leverage eloquent relations.

Comment: You are probably looking to use both angularjs and laravel blade. This might help: https://scotch.io/tutorials/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs

Comment: you did not get friend see `Offer::hired($record->id)` and `$record->submissions->count()`i can call these in foreach loop. How i can get some other data in ng-repeat base on some value on loop.